# Number of occurences in a MySQL Search and case insensitive

Tags: mysql

This is my SQL Query:

```
SELECT filename  
FROM video   
WHERE MATCH (title, description) AGAINST  
('sports' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I'm searching the `title` and `description` fields for the word `sports` (case insensitive)

Now I want to count the number of times that the word `score` appeared on those fields, but independently... So I want to get something like this: n_title=2, n_description=1.

I already have tried this query, and it works...

```
SELECT filename,  
ROUND ((LENGTH(description) - LENGTH( REPLACE ( description, "sports", ""))) / LENGTH("sports")) AS count  
FROM video
```

but it's not case insensitive, and when I type `sports` it doesn't came up with any results, because on the database it's "saved" as "Sports" (with the uppercase "S").

Now my problem is how can I "concatenate" this 2 queries, and use them as one. So I can search for any word case insensitive, and also count the number of occurrences from each field.

Comment: You must be using a case-sensitive collation. Please show us the current structure (`SHOW CREATE TABLE video`).

Comment: Here is the structure...
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c336a/2
I don't specified the charset because by default it should be case insensitive. However in my DB I have the `utf8`. Strange thing is that in sqlfiddle the same thing happens and the "sports" is case sensite with the second query...

Comment: maybe `UPPER` description and then replace 'SPORTS'

Comment: Are you saying to do this: ROUND ((LENGTH(UPPER (description)) - LENGTH( REPLACE (UPPER(description), UPPER("sports"), ""))) / LENGTH("sports")) AS count ??? This probably should work :)

Comment: Sorry I totally missed the point of your question earlier...

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for ([fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7f76/4)):

```
SELECT
    filename,  
    (
      CHAR_LENGTH(title)
      - CHAR_LENGTH( REPLACE(LOWER(title), "sports", "") )
    ) / CHAR_LENGTH("sports") AS cnt_title,
    (
      CHAR_LENGTH(description)
      - CHAR_LENGTH( REPLACE(LOWER(description), "sports", ""))
    ) / CHAR_LENGTH("sports") AS cnt_desc

FROM video
WHERE MATCH (title, description) AGAINST ('sports' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

[`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) is case-sensitive by definition. The trick is to handle a lowercased version of the string. Also, your should use `CHAR_LENGTH`instead of `LENGTH`. The former counts characters whereas the latter counts bytes (and you are using UTF8).

Comment: With some changes, but I get there! Thank you +1